# Matlab - Summing from control variable in loop to end of matrix and from beginning of matrix to control variable

Tags: matlab, loops, sum

As a part of a bigger script, I have a matrix 1738 * 2 (1738 rows - 2 columns) and I want to loop through the first column (so 1738 times). Dependent on the iteration of the loop I would like to sum up the the second column from the start value to the (control variable - 1) and from the control variable to the end of the second column. This is how i try to start with the loop through the first column - COG_Ton is the 1738 x 2 Matrix (the number of rows is dependent on the input-data).

My idea is something like this:

```
for ik = COG_Ton (:,1)
    tonnes(ik) = sum (COG_Ton (1:ik-1, 2)) 
    tonnes2(ik) = sum(COG_Ton (ik:end,2))
end
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can implement this in Matlab ?

Comment: What do you mean how to implemetn in MATLAB? that is MATLAB code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've written is quite similar in matlab code, but with some minor changes, see below:

```
for ik = 1:size(COG_Ton,1) length of column 1 in x
    tonnes(ik) = sum (COG_Ton (1:ik-1, 2));
    tonnes2(ik) = sum(COG_Ton (ik:end,2));
end
```

note the syntax in the for-statement. ik goes from 1 to size(COG_Ton,1), i.e. the length of column 1, which is 1738 in your example.

Comment: thanks a lot. does matlab now also take the increment which is specified in the first column ?

Comment: Happy to help :) I am not sure what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: for ik = 1:size(COG_Ton,1) length of column 1 in x - what does the second part of this mean ? and with this set up is the iteration through the first column in the steps of the column or in the steps of one ?

Comment: In steps of 1, i.e ik = 1,2,3,4,...,1737,1738.

Comment: this data is variable, but always in the same increment steps - right now it is in steps of 0.1 ... how do I implement that ? for ik = 1:0.1:size (COG_Ton,1) ? and is it possible that matlab reads the step from the matrix ?

Comment: so basically column one looks like (0, 0.1, 0.2 .... 1738) and column 2 stores the data to it

Comment: Oh I see, I thought you wanted to go through each index in COG_Ton. Exactly, use  `for ik = 1:0.1:size(COG_Ton,1)`. But then the rest of the code won't work. You are telling matlab that you want to sum the values of COG_Ton at indices 1 to ik-1 in column 2. Then ik must be an integer.

Comment: yeah i wanted to go through each index in column 1, ( they are just sized in steps of 0.1) but the step is variable dependent on data output... so if i use for ik 1: size (COG_Ton,1) then it goes through every row in column 1 right ? and thanks for you effort :)

Comment: Correct! :) If my answer was an acceptable solution, please click the check box by the vote count in my answer. I'd appreciate it ;)

Comment: I hope i can directly ask you the next question .... for parts of the next formula i have a part (ik+1)-ik ... still talking about the control variable and it gives out 1 ... although the step size is 0.1 and hence that should be the answer ... can i somehow tell matlab that with ik+1 i mean the next iteration and not actually ik+1 ? you are really saving my life here ;)

Comment: hey, i figured out that i need the for ik 1:0.1:size (COG_Ton,1) as otherwise only every 10th step is carried out (i need the iteration in steps of 0.1) but as you pointed out the rest of the code doesnt work now. is there a way to use non-integers as indices ?

Comment: so basically i have from 0 to 178 in steps of 0.1 and want to iterate through them

Comment: use: `for k = 1:size(COG_Ton,1)` and then inside the for loop, declare `ik = (k-1)*0.1`. Now you loop through the indices and you can use "k" wherever you want to use the index, and then use "ik" wherever you want the value. Let me know if it works out.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed things up using `cumsum` once and observing that `tonnes2(k) = sum(COG_Ton(:,2))-tonnes1(k)`:

```
cs = cumsum(COG_Ton(:,2), 1);
tonnes1 = cs(COG_Ton(:,1)-1); %// assuming for the k-th entry you sum up to COG_Ton(k,1)-1
tonnes2 = cs(end)-tonnes1;
```